# Odd behaviour with category anchor and layered navagation in M2

Tags: category, magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I have a catalog tree with 6 1st level categories, and up to 6 category layers below in sub-categories, for an approx total of 250 categories.

The problem we are having is that we need sub-categories to appear in the Layered Navigation menu, but no categories of any kind actually show up when Anchor = True is set for that category.

Is there a way to show the sub-categories in the Layered Nav while anchor = True ?